# Exact solution for ODE: $yy' + y + f(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there is exactly solution for ODE in the form: $yy'+y+f(x)=0$.  Thanks.

If there is no such solution for general $f$, does it ease the problem if $f(x)=Ax+B$ for some constants $A$ and $B$?

Clarification: solutions below are just particular solution.  What I was looking for is the general solution that works for arbitrary initial condition.

Comment: what kind of function is $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

you can solve $yy^\prime + y +ax +b = 0$ by the method of undetermined coefficients.

assume a solution of the form $y = cx + d, y^\prime = c,$ then we need
$$c(cx+d) + cx + d + ax + b = 0$$ that is $c^2 + c + a = 0, cd + d + b = 0$

so $c = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4a}}{2}$ provided $a \le 1/4$ and $d = -\dfrac{b}{1+c}.$

Comment: This is just a particular solution.  In the solution both $c$ and $d$ are determined by coefficients $a$ and $b$, thus, it doesn't solve for arbitrary initial condition.

Comment: @icando,  this de is singular at the $x$ values where $y$ is zero. i need to think more about singular points. it is a very particular de i have not seen too many of.

Answer (score 1):

There are two linear solutions, possibly complex:
$$y=Cx+D\\
C(Cx+D)+Cx+D=-Ax-B\\
C^2+C=-A,(C+1)D=-B$$
If you can write $f(x)=b_0+b_1e^{kx}+b_2e^{2kx}+b_3e^{3kx}+...$, and $y(x)=a_0+a_1e^{kx}+...$, (so they are polynomials in $e^{kx}$) then you can find the coefficients $a_i$ recursively, as functions of $b_i$.

Comment: This is just a particular solution.  In the solution both $c$ and $d$ are determined by coefficients $a$ and $b$, thus, it doesn't solve for arbitrary initial condition.